# Dealing with long inputs in python

Tags: python

I've been practicing on Google Code Jam previous contests and it's kind of my first time dealing with long inputs like that.

The problem is if the number is sorted in ascending order it's called tidy number the code will print the last tidy number between 1 and N I.e the last tidy number between 1 and 21 is 19.
The first line is the number of test cases then followed by number N for each case.

I've written the code the it works perfectly with short integers but when I input long integers it just stops.

Here is my code:

```
def isTidy(num):
if len(str(num)) == 1:
     return 1
number = str(num)
arr = []
arr2 = []
i = 0
while i < len(number):
    arr.append(number[i])
    i+=1
j=0
while j< len(number):
    arr2.append(number[j])
    j+=1
arr2.sort()
if arr == arr2:
    return 1
else:
    return 0

cases = int(raw_input())
i=0
tidy = -1
while i<cases:
number=raw_input()
j=1
while j < int(number) +1:
    if isTidy(j):
        tidy = j;
    j+=1
print "Case #"+str(i+1)+": " +str(tidy)   
i+=1
```

Here's the `I/O`:

```
10
132
1000
7
111111111111111110
905
391458953027532635
723897627649600590
11122233441
412223334467890000
522444557790

Case #1: 129
Case #2: 999
Case #3: 7
```

It just stops output after case 3 with no exceptions.

Comment: Could you provide some further background on the intent of the code?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
You haven't told us where it stops, what the program is supposed to do, or reduced the problem.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I've added a description of the problem.

Comment: How long do you wait for that inefficient algorithm to process all the numbers up to that looks like 18 digit number?

Comment: I've waited for like half an hour with no output yet.

Comment: I don't think that is as long as it will take that program to run up to that 18 digit number.  Change your input and see how long it takes to process a 5 or 6 digit number.

Comment: So the code is working but inefficient so it takes long time to proccess the numbers right?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me.